# Background with more than 1 color

Tags: css, html, background

I'm trying to add a background that is split in 3 parts. 5% gray on the left, white, 5% gray on the right...

SO I created a gradient with CSS, which is partially okay in Chrome but in IE it doesn't work at all...

How would you create the effect I'm looking for?

[Here is the website.](http://frenchegg.com)

Comment: Did you try to use a div for left and right margins?

Comment: No, how would you go about doing that?

Comment: What versions of IE does it have to be compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Css gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/):

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

`css` is too long so look in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pEB9X/2/)**.
This one works in IE 9.

---

Another option:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="white"></div>
</div>

<style>
body {  background: blue;}
.container {
    height: 50px;
    background: gray;
}
.white {
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 5%;
}
</style>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv6eD/)**

Answer (score 1):

CSS Gradients can cause havoc due to their lack luster support accross platforms. You would most likely want to do the div method mentiond by @Louis in the comments to your question. Something like this could work:

```
 <body>
 <div class="left"></div>
 <div class="center"></div>
 <div class="right"></div>
 <style>
 .left, .right{
     width:5%;
     background:gray;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
     margin:0;
 }
 .center{
     width:90%;
     background:white;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
     margin:0;
 }
 </style>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this website will help you to create css gradient
http://gradients.glrzad.com/
also try to run this in IE
there is support for the gradient in latest IE but i think not for old ones.
other solution is that make a photoshoped image of your own design and use this as your background image.